# Do I have to worry about Code Injection when I have no Database access in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, code-injection

I got a simple Site with a textbox where the user can enter some stuff. That Text is analysed and fancy stuff is done with it (like counting the words, displaying the text in another textbox)

No Database-Connection exists. No data is saved permanently

Do I still have to worry about code injection? 
Can something harmful be done?

Comment: What do you do with the text?  Do you store the text anywhere?  Do you send it via an email, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @nmat and want to add here that If you want to do check against the security, the only thing you need to consider is cross site scripting due to weird inputs in textbox. You can use [Anti-cross site scripting library for validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx). Same site is also having details regarding what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you implement the application behaviour, plenty of things could go wrong. You don't have to worry about SQL injection because you don't have a database, but you may have problems if you aren't careful with the submitted data.

Add [ASP validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the TextBox to ensure that the user only submits data that you expect to receive. Ex: add a maximum length, a regex or other custom validation. ASP validators work both on the client side and on the server side so this should be enough protection in this case.

Comment: Regex, max length etc. does not work as the purpose of the tool is to count words (in very long texts), reformat it and send it back to the user. The validators might be worth a look. Thanks